# Detect if new install or updated version (Android app)

Tags: android

I have an app on the Play Store. I want to put a requirement that if users want to use a certain part of the app, they have to invite a friend before being able to do so. But I only want to impose this restriction to new installs of the app (to be fair to users that have installed the app before the restriction). 
Sorry for the long intro, my question is how can I find out if the current device has updated the app or is a new install?

Comment: Does your app communicate with a backend? Do you have some way to identify users outside of the device itself?

Comment: Check if the old version of your app saves some data on disk or preferences, that is safe (i.e. that cannot be deleted by the user). When the new version is freshly installed, this data won't exist. If the new version is an upgrade from the old version, this data will exist.

Comment: I would insist to checkout preference data of existing version.

Comment: That sounds pretty good, not a perfect solution though because there is still a chance that older versions have nothing in SharedPrefereces. If there isn't a better solution, I will have to use that though.

Comment: @Hasam: AFAIK, your requirement is unique, and so is the solution. To identify existing users, you need to checkout their footprints in device only. and as you know, SharedPreference is one of the ways because it persists during updation. I hope you got what I mean to say.

Comment: @PhilippeA: As you have added comment before I did, Please post your suggestion as an answer so that it can be accepted by OP if he wish to.

Comment: @MehulJoisar yes I think you're right, it's too bad there isn't a full proof solution, but this seems like a logical one. Thanks guys

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer, thx @mehul-joisar ;)

Comment: Please check my answer, it does not rely on any prior behavior of your app.

Comment: That won't work, because I don't want to start detecting which are new from now on, I want to be able to say that this device has had a previous version of my app, hence I will do this.
Sorry if that's not clear, do read the comments on your answer if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
public static boolean isFirstInstall(Context context) {
    try {
        long firstInstallTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
        long lastUpdateTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
        return firstInstallTime == lastUpdateTime;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return true;
    }
}



public static boolean isInstallFromUpdate(Context context) {
    try {
        long firstInstallTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
        long lastUpdateTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
        return firstInstallTime != lastUpdateTime;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When answering questions it is best to explain in more detail so that it can be more easily understood by other users of the site.

Comment: this looks simpler than the accepted answer. does this work? have you tested it?

Comment: Very clean solution.

Comment: I've tested this and the firstInstallTime and lastUpdateTime is not same thing in this case. I've different results.

Comment: Wonderful solution works like a charm, Is there any way to unit test these two methods?

Comment: For me it's not working. If i keep opening the app repeatedly the firstInstallTime and lastUpdateTime are always different. I think is not possible the lastUpdateTime and firstInstallTime to be equal, only in the case it's fresh install.

Comment: Works well, but keep in mind if the user uninstalls the app and then installs it again - isFirstInstall will return true.

Comment: It does not work for Android 30 and both times are same, but on lower version it works correctly.

Answer (score 24):

The only solution I can see that doesn't involve an entity outside of the device would be to get the [`PackageInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) for your app and check the values of

- [`versionCode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode)
- [`firstInstallTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime)
- [`lastUpdateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#lastUpdateTime)

On first install, `firstInstallTime` and `lastUpdateTime` will have the same value (at least on my device they were the same); after an update, the values will be different because `lastUpdateTime` will change. Additionally, you know approximately what date and time you create the version that introduces this new behavior, and you also know which version code it will have.

I would extend `Application` and implement this checking in `onCreate()`, and store the result in `SharedPreferences`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // take the date and convert it to a timestamp. this is just an example.
    private static final long MIN_FIRST_INSTALL_TIME = 1413267061000L;
    // shared preferences key
    private static final String PREF_SHARE_REQUIRED = "pref_share_required";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        checkAndSaveInstallInfo();
    }

    private void checkAndSaveInstallInfo() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if (prefs.contains(PREF_SHARE_REQUIRED)) {
            // already have this info, so do nothing
            return;
        }

        PackageInfo info = null;
        try {
            info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // bad times
            Log.e("MyApplication", "couldn't get package info!");
        }

        if (packageInfo == null) {
            // can't do anything
            return;
        }

        boolean shareRequired = true;
        if (MIN_FIRST_INSTALL_TIME > info.firstInstallTime
                && info.firstInstallTime != info.lastUpdateTime) {
            /*
             * install occurred before a version with this behavior was released
             * and there was an update, so assume it's a legacy user
             */
            shareRequired = false;
        }
        prefs.edit().putBoolean(PREF_SHARE_REQUIRED, shareRequired).apply();
    }
}
```

This is not foolproof, there are ways to circumvent this if the user *really* wants to, but I think this is about as good as it gets. If you want to track these things better and avoid tampering by the user, you should start storing user information on a server (assuming you have any sort of backend).

Comment: Works perfectly! And I agree, the possibilities to circumvent this are kind of low .

Comment: version code will be the same, you can remove it from your question, it doesn't help if it wasn't been tracked from the first app version, but firstInstallTime and lastUpdateTime sounds interesting

Answer (score 7):

Check if the old version of your app saves some data on disk or preferences. This data must be  safe, i.e. it cannot be deleted by the user (I'm not sure it's possible).

When the new version is freshly installed, this data won't exist. If the new version is an upgrade from the old version, this data will exist.

Worst case scenario, an old user will be flagged as a new one and will have a restricted usage.

Comment: That's good. Thanks. The worst case isn't really that bad either.

Comment: It would be a good idea to check for any preference flag, which user might set, in order for the app to use (for eg. Terms of use agree, walkthrough etc). and also check for current app version, so that if old user comes, the flag will be set, if new user comes, the flag will be unset.

Answer (score 5):

A concise Kotlin solution, based off the still excellent wudizhuo answer:

```
 val isFreshInstall = with(packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)) {
     firstInstallTime == lastUpdateTime
 }
```

This can be called directly from within an `Activity` as an Activity is a context (so can access `packageManager` etc.)

If you wanted to use this in multiple places/contexts, it could very easily be turned into an extension property:

```
val Context.isFreshInstall get() = with(packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0)) {
    firstInstallTime == lastUpdateTime
}
```

This way, you can simply write `if (isFreshInstall)` in any Activity, or `if (requireContext().isFreshInstall)` inside any Fragment.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is use SharedPreference

```
private int getFirstTimeRun() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MYAPP", 0);
    int result, currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    int lastVersionCode = sp.getInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", -1);
    if (lastVersionCode == -1) result = 0; else
        result = (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) ? 1 : 2;
    sp.edit().putInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", currentVersionCode).apply();
    return result;
}
```

return 3 posibles values:

- 0: The APP is First Install
- 1: The APP run once time
- 2: The APP is Updated

Comment: Thanks! It's better if 1 is used for update and 2 for normal usage. Cause then we can use `if (status < 2) { // do post-install stuff }`

Answer (score 3):

### Update

*(thanks for the comments below my answer for prodding for a more specific/complete response).*

Because you can't really retroactively change the code for previous versions of your app, I think the easiest is to allow for all ***current*** installs to be grandfathered in.

So to keep track of that, one way would be to find a piece of information that points to a specific version of your app.  Be that a timestamped file, or a `SharedPreferences`, or even the `versionCode` (as suggested by @DaudArfin in his answer) from the last version of the app you want to allow users to not have this restriction.  Then you need to change this.  That change then becomes your reference point for all the previous installs.  For those users mark their `"has_shared"` flag to true.  They become *grandfathered* in.  Then, going forward, you can set the `"has_shared"` default to `true`

(Original, partial answer below)

### Use a **SharedPrefence** (or similar)

Use something like `SharedPreferences`.
This way you can put a simple value like `has_shared = true` and `SharedPreferences` will persist through app updates.

Something like this when they have signed someone up / shared your app

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("has_shared", true)
editor.commit();
```

Then you can only bug people when the pref returns true

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean defaultValue = false;
boolean hasShared= prefs.gettBoolean("has_shared", defaultValue);
if (!hasShared) {
    askUserToShare();
}
```

**Docs for SharedPreference:**
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: How does this solve his problem of only enforcing the share requirement for people who did not have the previous version of the app?

Comment: please read the question. it's not about how to preserve the state.it's about distinguish from old version.

Comment: Well you have to cut off the version somewhere, he hasnt been tracking who has the app installed, there is no way to magically reach into the past for that information.  But using this method, you can draw a line and make the requirement going forward.  But I see you point.  Unless there is some distinguishing characteristic from old versions (files saved, or preferences) there is no way to know if the user updated or installed fresh.

Comment: @pjco: man, there is always a way to achieve something. May be sometimes there is no `straight forward` way.

Comment: @MehulJoisar, I like the way you think :) Updated my answer a bit based on the feed back from you and Karakuri

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version code and version name using below code snippet

```
String versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;

int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

Now you can check for the latest version and restrict as per your requirement.

Comment: after updating the app, it will always return new version. so by using above approach, there is no way to distinguish whether it is updated or fresh install.

Comment: he knows from which version he want to restrict user i mean the older version name and code .. dat he need to compare dats all

Comment: Please read the question again, he does not want to restrict all the users of new version, he wants to restrict only the new users.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but then, Daud is right. You can use a boolean flag (in SharedPreferences) to detect if the user is a new user of the current version. Just mark it false if the immediately the action is performed.

Answer (score 1):

We can use broadcast receiver to listen app update.

**Receiver**

```
class AppUpgradeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

  @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    if (context == null) {
        return
    }
    Toast.makeText(context, "Updated to version #${BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE}!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
  }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".AppUpgradeReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
</intent-filter>
```

It doesn't work while debug. So you have to install to manually.

1. Increase the versionCode in your app-level build.gradle (so it counts as an update).
2. Click Build -> Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) -> Build APK(s), and select a debug APK.
3. Run following command in the terminal of Android Studio:

   ```
   adb install -r C:\Repositories\updatelistener\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any operation only once per update then follow below code snippet

```
private void performOperationIfInstallFromUpdate(){ 
try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String versionName = prefs.getString(versionName, "1.0");
        String currVersionName = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        if(!versionName.equals(currVersionName)){
            //Perform Operation which want execute only once per update
            //Modify pref 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(versionName, currVersionName);
            editor.commit();
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return BASE_VERSION;
    }
```

}