# change default preference on upgrade

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, upgrade

In my app, I have the following code that tells me if a feature is enabled by default :

```
public boolean getFeatureEnabled()
{
    return mPrefs.getBoolean("FEATURE_ENABLED", DEFAULT_ENABLED);
}
```

This preference is overwritten only when the user changes the setting from UI. So by default it draws its value from `DEFAULT_ENABLED` which is a class variable somewhere.

In the current version, `DEFAULT_ENABLED` is `true` but on the next version of my app will be `false`.

The problem is that after the update, with the above code the old users who did not change the default setting from UI will have their feature disable - and I want to avoid this.

Any advices on how to handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have a feature that was enabled by default but this default was never written to `SharedPreferences` unless explicitly changed by the user.
Now you want the feature to be disabled by default but without affecting the behavior for users that already have it enabled.

I can think of 3 options:

**Option 1** If you are already saving the last version, you could check that in your migration logic:

```
private void migratePreferences(Context context) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("your_preference_file", MODE_PRIVATE);

    int lastKnownVersionCode = (prefs.getInt("LAST_INSTALLED_VERSION", BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("LAST_INSTALLED_VERSION", BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE).apply();

    //this is the old featureEnabled check
    boolean oldPreferenceValue = prefs.getBoolean("FEATURE_ENABLED", true);

    boolean newPreferenceValue;
    if (prefs.contains("FEATURE_ENABLED")) {
        //the feature was modified by the user so respect their preference
        newPreferenceValue = prefs.getBoolean("FEATURE_ENABLED", false);
    } else if (lastKnownVersionCode == BUGGY_VERSION_WITH_FEATURE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT) {
        //the user is updating from the buggy version.
        // this check could include a range of versions if you've released several buggy versions.
        // this is also where option 2 would be inserted
        newPreferenceValue = oldPreferenceValue;
    } else {
        //the new default that will apply to fresh installs
        newPreferenceValue = false;
    }

    //save the preference
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("FEATURE_ENABLED", newPreferenceValue).apply();
}
```

This, however depends on your **already** having a call to this method somewhere in your app startup code.

**Option 2** In case you don't, there is still hope. You can check if this is your first install using the answers given [in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194960/338449)

**Option 3** You can release an intermediate version of your app that behaves as it does now but saves the unsaved default setting in `SharedPreferences`. This will keep the feature AS IS for your eager users but you will have to wait until a significant portion of users updates before releasing the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Put another flag "`FIRST_TIME`" as "`true`" in your `preferences` in new build. Check on the very first screen of your app

```
if(FIRST_TIME==true)
 {
 //put FEATURE_ENABLED = false;
 //put FIRST_TIME = false;

 }
```

By doing this `FEATURE_ENABLED` will set to false for the first time the user launches the app and will not consider the default value